# Jquery: Seleccionar un opción de un <select> dinámico desde un resultado con Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

El siguiente código hace una consulta a un archivo php donde retorna un solo valor que debe ser pasado a un select dinámico para mostrar la opción escogida anteriormente por el usuario para su edición:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  'ruta.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'opcion:consultar'},
    success:function(data){
       $("#nombredelselect").val(data);
    }
});
```

El problema que presenta es que no funciona, no asigna el valor al select. He intentado con:

```
$("#nombredelselect").val(data);

$("#nombredelselect option[value="+data+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');

$("#nombredelselect option[value="+data+"]").prop('selected', 'selected');
```

Y hasta ahora no funciona ninguna de la opciones, pero si coloco un alert(data) antes de la instrucción si asigna el valor al select.

```
$.ajax({
    url:  'ruta.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'opcion:consultar'},
    success:function(data){
       alert(data);
       $("#nombredelselect").val(data);
    }
});
```

De que manera se puede solucionar esta situación, ya que no debe mostrar ningún mensaje (alert) previo a mostrar la información en el select.

Para llenar el Select utilizo una función creada en javascript que realiza el llamado al servidor y me retorna los datos a cargar:

```
function cargarCategoria() {
    var i;
    var lsCategorias = $("#categoria");     
    lsCategorias.find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="0">Seleccione...</option>').val('');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'controller/categoria_controller.php',
        data: {evento:'listar_categorias'},
        success: function(data){
            var campo = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (campo) {
                for (i in campo) {
                    lsCategorias.append('<option value="' + campo[i].id_categoria + '">' + campo[i].nombre_categoria + '</option>');
                };
            }
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
};
```

Solo llamo la función en el archivo HTML y carga el Select.

Comment: Hola Arnaldo, varias preguntas: ¿Cómo es el HTML asociado al código (y cuándo se genera)?¿Y cómo es la respuesta del servicio al que llamas (texto plano, JSON, un array...)?

Comment: Hola Alvaro, el HTML está en un archivo separado el cuál tiene una etiqueta select con un id, que es cargado previo a la asignación del valor. Por otro lado la respuesta del servicio es en JSON. Lo más extraño es que con los input text la función .val() trabaja a la perfección. Gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Que funcione cuando hay un alert y no cuando el alert no está presente lo he visto antes en páginas en las que se creaba el elemento después de la llamada AJAX, y a veces se daba el caso de que la respuesta llegaba antes de la creación del elemento.

Comment: @Arnaldo podrías poner código de cómo llenas el select con tus datos incluyendo la peticion AJAX que usas para obtener esos datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podría ser debido a las peticiones AJAX porque son asincrónicas, de modo que la data llega antes de que se puede crear tu select en tu DOM. Prueba a desactivar la petición asincrónica con:

async: false,

```
$.ajax({
    url:  'ruta.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'opcion:consultar'},
    async: false,
    success:function(data){
       alert(data);
       $("#nombredelselect").val(data);
    }
});
```

Te recomiendo que uses métodos para encapsular y asegurar el orden con las que se realizan tus peticiones. Por otra parte, async: false, dará la misma sensación que un alert (congelar la página mientras recibe la respuesta) en este caso de tu servidor.

Por ultimo, evita "success:" y usa ".done()", más en: [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: `async: false,` no es una practica recomendada, no me parece buena idea colocarla como una sugerencia.

Comment: Tienes razón. A pesar de recomendar done, por buenas practicas, también sugerí async: false, el cual congela la página mientras recibe la respuesta del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Una idea que podrías tener es usar [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) para establecer el varlor más tarde, luego que que el `select` dinámico de haya llenado pero esto no es muy buena idea y la razón de esto es porque **nunca** se debe asumir el orden en que llegarán los resultados de las llamadas a AJAX. Hay un gran número de factores que pueden afectar el tiempo que toma una petición por lo que tienes que asumir que este es desconocido; aunque las hayas ejecutado primero pueden retornar en orden diferente.

Si te encuentras en una situación como esta es muy probable que debas reestructurar el código para usar **encadenamiento de promesas** o **unión de promesas** (depende de lo que se quiera lograr), de esta forma el código que quieres ejecutar se iniciará solamente cuando tengas todos los datos necesarios.

El método [then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) de jQuery retorna una promesa encadenable que puedes seguir llamando y puedes usar `return` para que el próximo paso de la cadena se ejecute con el resultado de la promesa anterior. Este es el sucesor del ahora obsoleto método [pipe](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

**Encadenamiento de promesas**

```
promesa1
    .then(function(resultadoPromesa1) { 
        // éxito
        return promesa 2;
    })
    .then(function(resultadoPromesa2) {
        // éxito
        return promesa3;
    }).then(function(resultadoPromesa3) {
        // éxito y fin de la cadena
    }, function() {
        // error. si algo en la cadena falla se ejecuta este código
    });
```

Debajo te dejo un demo de como deberías estructurar tu código.

```js
$(function() {
  var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
  $.ajax({
      url: 'datosselect.php',
      type: 'GET'
    })
    .then(function(selectData) {
      // llenar el select con datos
      $.each(selectData, function(index, item) {
        mySelect.append('<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.text + '</option>');
      });
      // retornar una promesa para el próximo then
      return $.ajax({
        url: 'ruta.php',
        type: 'GET'
      });
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      // establecer el valor en el select
      mySelect.val(data);
    }, function() {
      // si cualquiera de las dos peticiones fallan se ejecuta el alert
      alert('Un error ha ocurrido');
    });
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Plugin para simular las peticiones al servidor. 
// Este fragmento no pertenece a la respuesta
// Es necesario para que el demo funcione
$.mockjax({
  url: /datosselect.php$/,
  responseText: [{
    value: 1,
    text: 'opcion 1'
  }, {
    value: 2,
    text: 'opcion 2'
  }, {
    value: 3,
    text: 'opcion 3'
  }]
});
$.mockjax({
  url: /ruta.php$/,
  responseText: '2'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/master/dist/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

Como ves funciona pero tiene un pequeño problema y es que el `select` se llena y al rato su valor se cambia (cuando la otra petición llega). Para corregir esto y que se muestre inmediatamente lo que debes es usar el método [when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) que permite unir varias promesas y ejecutar código cuando **todas** se terminen.

**Unión de promesas**

```
$.when(promesa1, promesa2, promesa3)
    .then(function(resultado1, resultado2, resultado3) {
     //exito
}, function() {
    // error. si al menos una falla se ejecuta esto
});
```

Nota que el resultado de `when` para cada una de las peticiones es un arreglo donde el primer elemento es la respuesta de tu servidor

```js
$(function() {
  var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
  $.when(
      $.ajax({
        url: 'datosselect.php',
        type: 'GET'
      }),
      $.ajax({
        url: 'ruta.php',
        type: 'GET'
      })
    )
    .then(function(selectData, data) {
      // llenar el select con datos
      $.each(selectData[0], function(index, item) {
        mySelect.append('<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.text + '</option>');
      });
      // establecer el valor
      mySelect.val(data[0]);
    }, function() {
      // si cualquiera de las dos peticiones fallan se ejecuta el alert
      alert('Un error ha ocurrido');
    });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Plugin para simular las peticiones al servidor. 
// Este fragmento no pertenece a la respuesta
// Es necesario para que el demo funcione
$.mockjax({
  url: /datosselect.php$/,
  responseText: [{
    value: 1,
    text: 'opcion 1'
  }, {
    value: 2,
    text: 'opcion 2'
  }, {
    value: 3,
    text: 'opcion 3'
  }]
});
$.mockjax({
  url: /ruta.php$/,
  responseText: '2'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/master/dist/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

De esta forma tus peticiones se **inician** al mismo tiempo lo que reduce el tiempo total necesario para que tus datos se muestren en la pantalla.